# How to uncheck checkbox if one is unchecked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of checkboxes that I use to increase a price as they are checked.

My problem is that i have to uncheck them one by one if I want to see the price go down. I would like to be able to uncheck one checkbox in the middle and have the following ones unchecked automatically.

**For example :**
Price = 100 if checkbox1.checked --> Price = 120
if checkbox2.checked --> checkbox1.checked **and** Price = 140
if checkbox3.checked --> checkbox1.checked **and** checkbox2.checked **and** Price = 160
etc.

**What I would like to be able to do :**
if i uncheck checkbox2 --> checkbox3 is unchecked **and** Price = 120

```html
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P3" onclick="functionProjets()"><span></span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P4" onclick="functionProjets()"><span></span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P5" onclick="functionProjets()"><span></span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P6" onclick="functionProjets()"><span></span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P7" onclick="functionProjets()"><span></span></label>
    <p id="txtP3">OK 3</p>
    <p id="txtP4">OK 4</p>
    <p id="txtP5">OK 5</p>
    <p id="txtP6">OK 6</p>
    <p id="txtP7">OK 7</p>
```

**Here is my js :**

```
function functionProjets() {
    // get the checkbox
    var P3 = document.getElementById("P3");
    var P4 = document.getElementById("P4");
    var P5 = document.getElementById("P5");
    var P6 = document.getElementById("P6");
    var P7 = document.getElementById("P7");
    // get the text output
    var txtP3 = document.getElementById("txtP3");
    var txtP4 = document.getElementById("txtP4");
    var txtP5 = document.getElementById("txtP5");
    var txtP6 = document.getElementById("txtP6");
    var txtP7 = document.getElementById("txtP7");

    // if a checkbox is checked, but not others > display corresponding output
    if (P3.checked === false && P4.checked === false && P5.checked === false && P6.checked === false && P7.checked === false) {
        txtP3.style.display = "none";
        txtP4.style.display = "none";
        txtP5.style.display = "none";
        txtP6.style.display = "none";
        txtP7.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (P3.checked === true && P4.checked === false && P5.checked === false && P6.checked === false && P7.checked === false) {
        txtP3.style.display = "block";
        txtP4.style.display = "none";
        txtP5.style.display = "none";
        txtP6.style.display = "none";
        txtP7.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if ((P3.checked === false || true) && P4.checked === true && P5.checked === false && P6.checked === false && P7.checked === false) {
        P3.checked = true;
        txtP4.style.display = "block";
        txtP3.style.display = "none";
        txtP5.style.display = "none";
        txtP6.style.display = "none";
        txtP7.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if ((P3.checked === false || true) && (P4.checked === false || true) && P5.checked === true && P6.checked === false && P7.checked === false) {
        P3.checked = true; P4.checked = true;
        txtP5.style.display = "block";
        txtP3.style.display = "none";
        txtP4.style.display = "none";
        txtP6.style.display = "none";
        txtP7.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if ((P3.checked === false || true) && (P4.checked === false || true) && (P5.checked === false || true) && P6.checked === true && P7.checked === false) {
        P3.checked = true; P4.checked = true;
        P5.checked = true;
        txtP6.style.display = "block";
        txtP3.style.display = "none";
        txtP4.style.display = "none";
        txtP5.style.display = "none";
        txtP7.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if ((P3.checked === false || true) && (P4.checked === false || true) && (P5.checked === false || true) && (P6.checked === false || true) && P7.checked === true) {
        P3.checked = true;
        P4.checked = true;
        P5.checked = true;
        P6.checked = true;
        txtP7.style.display = "block";
        txtP3.style.display = "none";
        txtP4.style.display = "none";
        txtP5.style.display = "none";
        txtP6.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me in depth?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The answer of RAllen is clearer than my explications. It's exactly what i need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the task correctly, this can be achieved like so

```js
const elements = [];

addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
  for (let index=3; index<=7; index ++)
  {
    elements.push({
      check: document.getElementById("P" + index),
      text: document.getElementById("txtP" + index)
    });
  }
}

function functionProjets(element) {
    const selectedIndex = elements.findIndex((el) => el.check === element);
    let lastChecked = -1;
    for (let index=0; index<elements.length; index ++)
    {
      el = elements[index];
      if (index !== selectedIndex) {
        el.check.checked = index <= selectedIndex;
      }
      if (el.check.checked) {
        lastChecked = index;
      }
      el.text.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (lastChecked >= 0) {
      elements[lastChecked].text.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P3" onclick="functionProjets(this)"><span></span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P4" onclick="functionProjets(this)"><span></span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P5" onclick="functionProjets(this)"><span></span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P6" onclick="functionProjets(this)"><span></span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="20" class="tarifsuppl" id="P7" onclick="functionProjets(this)"><span></span></label>
<p id="txtP3">OK 3</p>
<p id="txtP4">OK 4</p>
<p id="txtP5">OK 5</p>
<p id="txtP6">OK 6</p>
<p id="txtP7">OK 7</p>
```

Please let me know if this help.

Comment: Yes thank you it's exactly that ! But when i copy your code js to replace mine, it doesn't work anymore... Do i miss somthing ?

Comment: No worries! I've updated the answer. You probably need a handler to capture elements after the page fully loads. I've added the handler to the code. Try to copy the updated code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Wanda please also note that in the HTML section I'm using `onclick="functionProjets(this)"` instead of `onclick="functionProjets()"`. This is an important piece to make the logic work.

Comment: Hi @Wanda have you had a chance to try the updated version of the code? Don't you mind upvoting and marking my answer as the solution if it helped you? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RAllen ! Sorry for the delay (i didn't have the time this weekend) and THANK YOU VERY MUCH it works totally like i wanted ! I mark your answer as the solution right now :) Thanks a lot again !!!

Comment: your code is perfect but i don't understand it... i would like to be able to uncheck the checkbox P3 to come back to zero. How can i do that ?

Comment: @Wanda No worries! I've updated the code to make it possible to uncheck the first checkbox. Please verify if it works as expected now.

Comment: Thank you for your update but now when the checkboxes are checked, all the outputs "textP" are displayed

Comment: @Wanda Updated the code again. Sorry, I totally forgot that only the last selected item must be shown.